# Create custom rule to Eclipse-cs

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I basically need to validate if some **js** files (present in specific directories) contain a special comment, that among other things contain the relative path of the file in the project.

So I was trying to add a custom rule into Eclipse-cs, so I followed the example from http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/#!/extensions and I was able to make it work, but.... it's only validating against **java** files and I need to make it validate against **js** files.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Presumably the js files contain JavaScript which, despite the name, is not related to Java. Checkstyle does not support JavaScript.

Comment: I know that Javascript and Java are not related, I was just wondering if it was possible to tell eclipse-cs to handle them, just like RegexpSingleline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by extending the **AbstractFileSetCheck** instead of **Check** class and implementing the following methods:

```
public void beginProcessing(String aCharset)
protected void processFiltered(File aFile, List<String> aLines)
```